# Hot to display latest saved image from django form?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i'm uploading image in my django form and and displaying them all at same time. I want to know how to display latest image after submitting that form. Any help would be appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    action = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CHOICES)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UploadModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = [
            'action',
            'image'
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
def picture_create_view(request, pk=id, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = {'form':form,'up':Upload.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]}
            return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
    else:
        form = UploadModelForm()
    return render(request, "upload.html", {"form": form})
```

I think problem is with line in views.py

`context = {'form':form,'up':Upload.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]}`

**upload.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

    {%for i in up %}
    <img src ="{{i.image.url}}", alt="">
    {%endfor%}

{% endblock %}
```

I know code in upload.html also have to change with views.py any suggestion will be appreciated also.
I'm using neural network with image field and i'm sure it works correctly. I cant paste that code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your **Views.py** just use **all().last()**

```
def picture_create_view(request, pk=id, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = {'form':form,'up':Upload.objects.all().last()}
            return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
    else:
        form = UploadModelForm()
        context = {'form':form,'up':Upload.objects.all().last()}
    return render(request, "upload.html", context)
```

**upload.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>

    
    <img src ="{{up.image.url}}", alt="">
```

Comment: TypeError at /
'Upload' object is not iterable

Comment: this is the error i'm getting. I tried that before and latest() also.

Comment: You have to remove for loop in your template. I changed the answers.